# Can I use a python program and convert it into a gui using tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a python password management system program and I am looking to see if I can convert it into a gui based program.

a snippet from the program :

```
def signup():
    f = open(signup_file,'r')
    print('Sign-up procedure')
    print()
    name = str(input('Enter your username (minimum 4 characters, no whitespaces) : '))
    if len(name)<4 or ' ' in name:
        return 'Invalid username input'
    if user_exists(name) == True:
        return 'Username already exists. Please choose another username!'
    password = str(input('Enter your password (minimum 8 characters, should not contain whitespace or exceed 16 characters): '))
    if password == name:
        return 'Please dont use the username as the password! '
    if ' ' in password or len(password)>16 or len(password)<8:
        return 'Invaild password input'
    
    c_password=str(input('Confirm your entered password : '))
    
    #Salted-hashing
    salt = hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(60)).hexdigest().encode('ascii')
    passhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)
    passhash = binascii.hexlify(passhash)
    final_password = (salt + passhash).decode('ascii')
    
    if c_password != password:
        return 'Passwords do not match !'
    else:
        #user_file0 = str(uuid.uuid4().hex)+'.txt' (for random file name)
        user_file0 = name + '_file.txt'
        fw = open(signup_file,'a')
        entry = name + ' ' + final_password + ' ' + user_file0 + '\n'
        fw.write(entry)
        return 'Sign-up completed'
        fw.close()
    f.close()
```

I have many other functions and a menu based on idle, so is there any way to convert this into a gui without rewriting the entire code?

Comment: Sorry, you have to start from scratch.

Comment: This a a common problem: how to use the same processing through various human interfaces. The answer is low coupling. If you encapsulate the algorithmic part in functions and classes, you will be able to share it. But if the more complex part is the interface itself, the only gain will be maintainability: if you later use a different scheme for password encoding, you will change it in one single place.

Comment: @SergeBallesta sorry but that seems too complex for my school project 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step, modify your signup function to take the inputs as parameters instead of using `input`.

```
def signup(signup_file, name, password):
    f = open(signup_file,'r')
    if len(name)<4 or ' ' in name:
        return 'Invalid username input'
    if user_exists(name) == True:
        return 'Username already exists. Please choose another username!'
    if password == name:
        return 'Please dont use the username as the password! '
    if ' ' in password or len(password)>16 or len(password)<8:
        return 'Invaild password input'
    
    #Salted-hashing
    salt = hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(60)).hexdigest().encode('ascii')
    passhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)
    passhash = binascii.hexlify(passhash)
    final_password = (salt + passhash).decode('ascii')
    
    #user_file0 = str(uuid.uuid4().hex)+'.txt' (for random file name)
    user_file0 = name + '_file.txt'
    fw = open(signup_file,'a')
    entry = name + ' ' + final_password + ' ' + user_file0 + '\n'
    fw.write(entry)
    fw.close()
    f.close()
    return 'Sign-up completed'
```

By the way, you should only `return` after closing the files!

The passwords-match check was removed, this should be done in the GUI.

Second step, make your GUI and have it call the function. Here an example, using the `ascii-designer` library (Disclaimer: I am the author)...

```
from ascii_designer import set_toolkit, AutoFrame

set_toolkit('tk')

class SignupForm(AutoFrame):
    f_body = """
        |           |
         result
         Name:       [ name_      ]
         Password:   [ password_  ]
         Confirm:    [ cpassword_ ]
                        [ OK ]
    """
    def f_on_build(self):
        self.label_result = ''
        self.name = ''
        self.password = ''
        self.cpassword = ''
        # TODO: Setup password and cpassword to not show cleartext.

    def on_ok(self):
        if self.password != self.cpassword:
            self.label_result = 'Passwords do not match'
        else:
            result = signup('accounts.txt', self.name, self.password)
            self.label_result = result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SignupForm().f_show()
```